# How can I use `select.select()` with `readline()`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, select

Sample code:

```
import os
import select

r, w = os.pipe()
rf = open(r, "rb")
wf = open(w, "wb")
wf.write(b"abc\n")
wf.write(b"def\n")
wf.flush()
for ii in range(2):
    select.select([rf], [], [])
    print(rf.readline())
```

This only prints out the first line, not the second line that is written to the pipe; it hangs before that is written out.

I assume that what is going on is that `readline()` reads a chunk of text and looks for a newline; because there is now nothing actually buffered in the pipe, `select()` doesn't return.

What's the best way around this?  I can't just call `realine()` repeatedly because that call will block when it finds there is no data waiting, which defeats the point of using select.

Ideally the solution would work for both sockets and pipes (because I'm writing socket code and then mocking the sockets with pipes for unit testing).

I've tried implementing `readline()` myself, reading one character at a time and looking for the newline, to try to leave something in the OS buffer but that seems to suffer from the same problem.